# css gradient giving scrollbar

Tags: css, linear-gradients

Hey i made css gradient using one of css gradient generators and i put in my code in usual way as it always worked, now...somehow gradient makes my page to have scrollbar and also if u will look better in my gived link u will see some squares at the bottom corners.
this is my style code, and markup is quite clean just html, body tags with nothing inside....

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    background-position: fixed;
    background: #ccffcc;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(161,219,255) 0%, rgb(204,255,204) 22%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(161,219,255) 0%, rgb(204,255,204) 22%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(161,219,255) 0%, rgb(204,255,204) 22%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(161,219,255) 0%, rgb(204,255,204) 22%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(161,219,255) 0%, rgb(204,255,204) 22%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0, rgb(161,219,255)),
        color-stop(0.22, rgb(204,255,204))
    );
}
```

example http://driglou.pusku.com/javascript/

Comment: In addition to the other recommendations, I'd recommend applying the background image to `html` *or* `body`, but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `body` style to `margin: 0` and you'll be ok.

You better look for a `CSS Reset` code and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing margins from the body:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```